# OnClickListeners not firing when Fragment initiated

Tags: java, android, facebook-android-sdk, android-annotations

I have exhausted all efforts on trying to figure out this problem. I am building an app with facebook login. I am using Android Facebook SDK 3.0 and the process works flawlessly. The problem comes with the other buttons on the screen. They are not firing when i have this code in the OnCreate

```
    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
            mainFragment = new FacebookFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment)
            .commit();
        } else {
            // Or set the fragment from restored state info
            mainFragment = (FacebookFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
        }
```

Using androidannotations i use

```
 @ViewById Button login_butt,reg_butt;
 @Click
 void login_butt(){
    login();
 }
 @Click
 void reg_butt(){
    startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,RegisterActivity_.class));
 }
```

which under the covers amount to the same thing as the code i have posted below. I have tried both ways and both have failed

My Listeners are

```
login_butt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            login();
        }
    });
    reg_butt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,RegisterActivity_.class));
        }
    });
```

At first i thought the problem lied in the androidannotations in which i am using but when removed the same problem presented itself.

My XML for the buttons are

```
 <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/authButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/reg_butt"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/password_enter"
    android:background="@drawable/register_select" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/login_butt"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/reg_butt"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/reg_butt"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/login_select" />
```

Comment: please post your entire onCreate method, I think you missing setting the button references... do you have `reg_butt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reg_butt)`?

Comment: I don't know if you are familiar with androidannotations but i have used it throughout my entire app without flaws. For this activity i have tried not using its functionality with no success. and es i had them defined with findViewById

Answer (score 2):

In which component are your buttons ? According to your explanations, I think they are in the fragment. So, do you have the `@EFragment` annotation on this class ?

Furthermore, you should start your fragment in [AndroidAnnotation way](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Enhance-Fragments) to enabled the library for this component and so register the listeners on your buttons.

Comment: the listeners are in the activity, but i will ill try reworking it with initiating the fragment the AA way.